# How to programmatically stop JMS listeners from consuming?

Tags: java, jms, weblogic

How to stop JMS consumers in WebLogic?

I need to programmatically notify WebLogic to stop JMS listeners (MDBs). What I mean by that is to stop consumption of messages of the queue, and start it again later also by code.

The Admin Console might have an option for that (maybe stop the factory?), but we need to do it in the code.

Something equivalent to Spring's [DefaultMessageListenerContainer.stop()](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html#stop-java.lang.Runnable-).

Comment: The equivalent in Weblogic is `pauseConsumption()` on the destination mBean. You can do it thru the admin console, via WLST scripting, or Java JMX programatically. The following links show each way: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/pagehelp/JMSjmsdestinationsjmsqueuepauseconsumptiontitle.html http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=6687 http://khylo.blogspot.com/2011/02/weblogic-jms-pause-and-resume.html

Comment: @castling It worked (the JMX approach). Can you post your answer so I can mark it as answered? Also, do you have any idea if that method applies for all cluster nodes?

Comment: Done - feel free to edit the answer if you have additional details that may be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent in Weblogic is `pauseConsumption()` on the destination mBean. Pausing should affect anything the destination is "targeted" to - which could be a cluster or a single server.

You can do it thru the admin console, via WLST scripting, or Java JMX programatically. The following links show all 3 methods:

### Via the admin console:

```
JMS Modules -> <Module Name> -> Destination Name -> Pause Consumption
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/pagehelp/JMSjmsdestinationsjmsqueuepauseconsumptiontitle.html

### Via WLST scripting:

```
cd('JMSRuntime/'+serverName+'.jms/JMSServers/'+jmsServerName+'/Destinations/'+jmsModName+'!'+ queueName)
cmo.pauseProduction()
```

http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=6687

### Via Java JMX:

```
for (String queueName : queueNames) {
  exception = null;
  try {
    ObjectName destination = findQueueObjectName(con, jmsModuleName, queueName);
    Object pauseConsResult = con.invoke(destination,"pauseConsumption", null, null);
```

http://khylo.blogspot.com/2011/02/weblogic-jms-pause-and-resume.html